# php DOMDocument - Get outer node and Protect <![CDATA[]] blocks as string

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a xml file and some of it nodes has a CDATA Block like this:

```
<item> 
  <content>OneWord</content>
</item>
<item> 
  <content><![CDATA[Some Text or Serialized arrays]]></content>
</item>
```

And I tried to get outer node as bellow:

```
$file = 'file.xml';
$contents = file_get_contents( $file );
$dom = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$dom->loadXML( $contents, LIBXML_NOCDATA );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

// -- get outer
$item = $xpath->query( './item' )->item(1);
$str = $dom->saveXML($item);
var_dump($str);
```

And it print item node without CDATA block but I want that node has CDATA Blocks.

Thanks

Comment: If you want CDATA blocks to be preserved, then why use `LIBXML_NOCDATA` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not as simple as removing the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` option ("[Merge CDATA as text nodes](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php)")?

For me,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$dom->loadXML( $contents );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

// -- get outer
$item = $xpath->query( './item' )->item(1);
$str = $dom->saveXML($item);
var_dump($str);
```

outputs

```
string '<item>
 <content><![CDATA[Some Text or Serialized arrays]]></content>
</item>' (length=78)
```